# What happens when the Runner stack is empty?

Tags: android-netrunner

When the corporation R&D is empty the corporation loses.  What happens when the Runner's stack is empty?

I think that: He must finish the game with only the cards on the table.

or

I doubt that: He reshuffles the heap into a new stack.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your instinct is correct; the runner continues to play with the cards that he/she has in play.

It would have been nice if the rules clarified this a little, but since they don't specify that anything special happens you carry on playing.

Despite the runner being able to continue playing, the runner can no longer draw cards and therefore becomes prone to getting flat-lined (having to trash more cards than there are in their hand) and losing that way.

This is fairly rare occurrence, since the corporation draws every turn, whereas the runner doesn't necessarily. Usually the corporation would deplete their deck before the runner, ending the game that way.

**Related Links:**

- http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/853237/depleted-runner-stack
- http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/877799/if-the-runner-runs-out-of-cards-in-his-stack-can-h

Comment: I've been playing the game since it came out and only realized the runner didn't reshuffle until two days ago! Our Anarch games are going to change drastically, as our primary strategy was to rip through our decks with `Wyldside` and `Disel` to get all our Viruses back quickly. Changes things quite dramatically for us

Comment: I disagree that this is rare, runners tend to play a lot of draw effects like [Diesel](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20038) or [Earthrise Hotel](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/06120) since they don't need to worry about decking out like a corp does and of course there is [MaxX](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07029) her deck _is_ going to empty as would a well built [Geist](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08063) deck. These decks usually play [Levy AR Lab Access](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03035) to reset the deck, but even then they wait until they need it.